# Dynamically Horizontal View Paging

Tags: android

hy!

I have a activity which shows a userprofile (photo,age etc). 
The count of userprofiles is dynamically (the user_ids comes from my webservice).

The activity will be called with a extra (user_id) and it loads all data from the web.

Now i want to make a Dynamic Horizontal View Paging (the count of Views is dynamic). As example i use http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/ ,but there he only switches the layout.

My Code:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private int cnt;

    public void setCount(int cnt)
    {
        this.cnt = cnt;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return cnt;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        //View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        View v = new View (MyPagerAdapter.this);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Please help

PS: I also use the Greendroid Library, but the example code (https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid/blob/master/GDCatalog/src/com/cyrilmottier/android/gdcatalog/PagedViewActivity.java) is harder to understand

Comment: You'll probably need to elaborate on what problem you are having. It isn't very clear why what you have now is not satisfactory.

Comment: Yeah i have to say the same. What you have won't work at all. Please add the full code of this class, or read further instructions for the viewpager.

Comment: Oh and it won't work if you try to get the view of your PagerAdapter like here... Is there no method instiateView or something else where you have to create the specific view itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to start with the following adapter:

```
private class PhotoSwipeAdapter extends PagedAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.paged_view_item, parent, false);
            }

            ((TextView) convertView).setText(Integer.toString(position));

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

It is more like the one you need. And like you see the getView Method return the specific View for the current page. You can fill it with stuff you like. In the above example it is a layout file. You can also create the layout  per code, but with an layout file it's easier!

Oh and to finalize this answer. (No-one else knows the tutorial you sent me, please add all ressources, even if they are only links or more difficult! Only if you add everything we can help you best)
- > The tutorial you followed doesn't use the GreenDroid Library, the Tutorial uses Androids Compatiblity Library. GreenDroid has an extra version of PageAdapter (Correct me if i'm wrong). You should always follow and use sample apps, you can find for the specific library you use. It is also important to read all details in tutorials -> the page says "Horizontal view paging is based upon APIs only available with the Android Compatibility package v4, Revision 3; these APIs are not available in the standard Android SDK at this time. "